# send 300K records as API response in Ruby and Sinatra

Tags: ruby, web-services, api, sinatra

My application has an end point for POST request. When ever the request is made for this POST request end point, it queries and fetches records from Mysql table (table containing 3.5 million records) and selects around 300K records.

It reads this 300k records and sends this data to the client as API response in JSON format.

This request and response takes around 15 minutes to send back 300K records as JSON response. Which is very slow in performance and really not acceptable by the clients.

Is there any quick way to send out 300K records as Json format in API response.?

Comment: You might consider switching to Postgresql and use the database to generate JSON directly. There was in [blog article about this](http://hashrocket.com/blog/posts/faster-json-generation-with-postgresql) a while ago.

Comment: What about caching the JSON with Redis?

Comment: http://over9000.org/rails/high-performance-rails-caching-with-redis-and-nginx

Comment: *"request and response takes around 15 minutes"* - find out where that time is being spent. How long does it take to execute the query, how long does it take to generate the JSON and how long does it take to send the data?

Comment: @Stefan I think lots of time is being spent on sending data via API.

Comment: @joe that sounds like guessing to me ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add the [oj](https://github.com/ohler55/oj) gem to your project.